# Sending email with Windows 8 Mail (Modern UI) being blocked by AVG Firewall

Tags: windows-8, avg-antivirus

I've setup my Outlook.com email address in Windows 8 Mail (Modern UI) but is unable to send and receive emails when my AVG Internet Security 2012 Business Edition's Firewall is enable.

When I disable the firewall, the emails are coming through and are being send.

I know that I can most probably open the ports for IMAP on the firewall, but instead I would like to permit the application.

Where/how do I find the application path for Windows 8 Mail (Modern UI) to allow all network traffic? (AVG did not show its normal Allow/Disallow notification for 1st time communications)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I would create an exception for the program in question and allow all traffic by the application.  Any specific questions about how to do this with AVG Internet Security 2012 Business Edition should be directed towards AVG Technologies.  Furthermore its clear that your security software does not fully support Windows 8 at this time.  I would just use a better product.

Comment: @Ramhound. See my comment on Journeyman Geeks's answer. I'm aware of directing specific questions to AVG Technologies themselves, my question was on how to find the path of the Windows 8 Mail (Modern UI) application in order to create an exclusion rule.

Comment: Just received feedback from AVG themselves regarding this issue. Although AVG 2012 is compatible with Windows 8, AVG Firewall 2012 is not. One needs to upgrade to the 2013 version of AVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a little tricky - to find, but I *think* the pathname is something like `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_16.4.4206.722_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\LiveComm.exe` - apparently in the past, [blocking this blocked a related modern-ui](http://messengergeek.wordpress.com/2012/02/) app so this SHOULD be of interest.

`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_16.4.4206.722_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WWAHost.exe` is also of interest - [since this is the runtime used to run JS/HTML5 apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465143.aspx)

Finding this was tricky to say the least - I started up [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and [openfileview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html), then  I started up mail, then quickly switched over to process explorer again to look for files that looked interesting in openfileview (which showed me `Microsoft.WindowsLive.Mail.etl   C:\Users\geek\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Microsoft.WindowsLive.Mail.etl`) and in process explorer for suspended apps.

[image]

I'm not sure if the wierd looking bits of the path are randomly generated.

Poking through the modern mail folder at `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_16.4.4206.722_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ModernMail\` indicates this is a wholly HTML5 application, so I guess each of these has a copy of LiveComm to run it.

Comment: Unfortunately, after adding the applications specified to the allow list, it is still not working. AVG IS 2013 Business Edition is to be released some time this month or next month. Hopefully they will have better Windows 8 support than the 2012 version, but you did answer my question as to how to find the application paths.